# Documents classification using SVM

Tags: libsvm, svm

Which is the best SVM algorithm for a document classification project?

Answer (score 2):

Document classification tasks typically feature high dimensional, sparse input spaces when you use a [bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) vectorization of the documents (typically in [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) form). This is an ideal scenario for linear SVM. An important publication which inspired many researchers to use linear SVM for document classification is "*Text Categorization with Support Vector Machines*" by Thorsten Joachims, available [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/People/tj/publications/joachims_98a.pdf).

It is recommended to use specialized linear SVM packages (such as LIBLINEAR, SVMPERF, PEGASOS) for this type of task since they are much much faster than general SVM packages when training a linear SVM.